# "Ci sta": vero significato e provenienza dell'espressione

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin

Buongiorno,

Volevo chiedere qual è il significato dell'espressione "ci sta" o "il che ci sta" dopo la descrizione di un comportamento di qualcuno o di un gruppo di persone o di una situazione. L'ho vista e sentita usare molte volte recentemente, anche se dove abito sembra che non si usi. Da dove proviene quest'espressione e cosa significa veramente?

La mia interpretazione personale, alla quale sono arrivato indovinando, è che significa "va bene che sia così" o "a me va bene che sia così".

Grazie per le chiarificazioni.

Per esempio:

> Se hai deciso di andartene al mare e fregatene dei tuoi doveri, perché
>   eri esausta, anche questo (comportamento) ci sta. Però non devi farlo
>   sempre.

Comment: “Sta”, non *“stà”.

Comment: Grazie per la correzione. Puoi elaborare una risposta? Grazie.

Comment: Per chi ha proposto di chiudere la domanda in quanto “unclear”: trovo che sia perfettamente chiara e che chieda informazioni su un uso che è anche registrato su alcuni dizionari.

Answer (score 4):

Un uso classico di “starci” è quello riferito a persone (“Facciamo un regalo a Mario? Luigi ha già detto che ci sta”). L'uso menzionato in questa domanda è invece molto più recente, probabilmente non diffuso in tutta Italia e ha come soggetto una cosa, in genere una situazione, come nell'esempio sull'andare al mare riportato nella domanda.

Dei vocabolari a cui ho accesso, gli unici che riportano questo uso di “starci” sono le attuali ultime edizioni dello Zingarelli (2020) e del Devoto-Oli.

Il primo, all'interno della lunga voce “stare”, dà vari usi per “starci” (essere contenuto, trovarsi, accettare etc.), tra cui:

> *ci sta che*, (colloq.) è possibile, è accettabile, è verosimile che: *ci sta che lei se la sia presa*; *ci sta che la squadra sia un po' stanca*

Similmente, il Devoto-Oli registra:

> fig. colloq., *ci sta*, *ci può stare* (o *può starci*),  è possibile, è verosimile (anche con prop. soggettiva + *di* e inf. o + *che* e cong.): *“Le finestre sono buie: magari non è in casa?” “Ci sta”*; *ci può stare **di** arrivare in ritardo, **che** il treno sia in ritardo*

In base alle situazioni in cui ho visto e sentito usare questa espressione, sottolineerei più il senso di “è accettabile” dato dallo Zingarelli rispetto al semplice “è possibile” del Devoto-Oli. Come nell'esempio dell'OP, spesso il senso è che il parlante non approva o non è del tutto d'accordo con uno stato di cose ma appunto lo accetta.

Un aspetto interessante della voce del Devoto-Oli è che questo uso viene trattato nello stesso punto della definizione in cui si descrive “stare” e “starci” nel senso di “poter essere contenuto in uno spazio, trovare posto, entrare” (“nella valigia non ci sta più nulla”), suggerendo che quello di cui parliamo sia un uso figurato di questo.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere la ragione del voto negativo.